# Accessing consumed React.Context in Next.js getInitialProps using HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am attempting to abstract my API calls by using a simple service that provides a very simple method, which is just an HTTP call. I store this implementation in a React Context, and use its provider inside my `_app.js`, so that the API is globally available, but I have a problem at actually consuming the context in my pages.

**pages/_app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'

import ApiProvider from '../Providers/ApiProvider';

import getConfig from 'next/config'
const { serverRuntimeConfig, publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()

export default class Webshop extends App 
{
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
        let pageProps = {}

        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        }

        return { pageProps }
    }

    render () {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

        return (
            <Container>
                <ApiProvider endpoint={publicRuntimeConfig.api_endpoint}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </ApiProvider>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

**Services/Api.js**

```
import fetch from 'unfetch'

function Api (config)
{
    const apiUrl = config.endpoint;

    async function request (url) {
        return fetch(apiUrl + '/' + url);
    };

    this.decode = async function (code) {
        const res = request('/decode?code=' + code);
        const json = await res.json();
        return json;
    }

    return this;
}

export default Api;
```

**Providers/ApiProvider.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Api from '../Services/Api';

const defaultStore = null;

class ApiProvider extends React.Component
{
    state = {
        api: null
    };

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state.api = new Api({ endpoint: props.endpoint });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <ApiContext.Provider value={this.state.api}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ApiContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export const ApiContext = React.createContext(defaultStore);
export default ApiProvider;
export const ApiConsumer = ApiContext.Consumer;
export function withApi(Component) {
    return function withApiHoc(props) {
        return (
            <ApiConsumer>{ context => <Component {...props} api={context} /> }</ApiConsumer>
        )
    }
};
```

**pages/code.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { withApi } from '../Providers/ApiProvider';

class Code extends React.Component
{
    static async getInitialProps ({ query, ctx }) {
        const decodedResponse = this.props.api.decode(query.code); // Cannot read property 'api' of undefined

        return {
            code: query.code,
            decoded: decodedResponse
        };
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                [...]
            </div>
        );
    }
}

let hocCode = withApi(Code);
hocCode.getInitialProps = Code.getInitialProps;
export default hocCode;
```

The problem is that I am unable to access the consumed context. I could just make a direct `fetch` call within my `getInitialProps`, however I wanted to abstract it by using a small function that also takes a configurable URL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have faced similar issues when trying to access contexts in functional components using `Context.Consumer` API. Have you tried to convert it into a class component using `static contextType = ApiContext`. Not a solution but it will help you find out if this is the issue

Comment: The proben is that getInitialProps is a static method and hence you can't access class instance properties from within it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Oh right... That's so obvious. How can I do something like this, then? I need to pass it as an argument of the getInitialProps from my HOC, right? That's also what I have tried, however I can not access React.Context data programmatically, if I wrap my Component with the Consumer context, getInitialProps won't be called properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access an instance of your provider in as **static** method `getInitialProps`, it was called way before the React tree is generated (when your provider is available).

I would suggest you to save an **Singelton** of your API in the API module, and consume it inside the `getInitialProps` method via regular import.

Or, you can inject it to your componentPage inside the `_app` getInitialProps, something like that:

```
// _app.jsx
import api from './path/to/your/api.js';

export default class Webshop extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
        let pageProps = {}
        ctx.api = api;

        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        }

        return { pageProps }
    }

    render () {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

        return (
            <Container>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

// PageComponent.jsx

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Code extends React.Component
{
    static async getInitialProps ({ query, ctx }) {
        const decodedResponse = ctx.api.decode(query.code); // Cannot read property 'api' of undefined

        return {
            code: query.code,
            decoded: decodedResponse
        };
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                [...]
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Code;
```

Does it make sense to you?

Comment: So instead of using React.Context, you suggest to use a singleton approach?

Comment: Yes, that singelton can be injected to all the page components I suggested.

Comment: This way I could even only import it exactly where I need it, instead of injecting it globally, right?